# while installing wifi driver 802.11n i got error about daemonize on lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lubuntu, realtek-wireless, dongle

[error while installing the wifi driver 802.11n realtek, could not resolve due unkonw error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQYQP.png)

Comment: Couple of things do not link to a picture of text include text in the question, There is not clear question here just a picture of some messages. 16.04 is out of support on April 22 time to upgrade.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.